# TSQL decimal precision issues when dividing

Tags: t-sql, math, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue with dividing numbers in TSQL. I have read the [Precision, scale, and length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) page but still I cannot figure out why the following issue occurs:

```
PRINT 1.4259276982890801000000/0.4259276982890801000000
-- Result 3.347816317222208

DECLARE @VAR1 DECIMAL(30,22) = 1.4259276982890801000000
DECLARE @VAR2 DECIMAL(30,22) = 0.4259276982890801000000
PRINT @VAR1/@VAR2
-- Result 3.34781631
```

**question**

- So why do I see a different precision in those cases while the numbers are exactly the same?
- How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The actual precision and scale of the literals in the first `PRINT` statement are `decimal(23,22)` and `decimal(22,22)`. Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql), the result type is decimal(38,15). You can observe this with `sp_describe_first_result_set`:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 1.4259276982890801000000;';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 0.4259276982890801000000;';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 1.4259276982890801000000/0.4259276982890801000000;';
```

The variables are both `decimal(30,22)` so the result is `decimal(38,8)`:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
DECLARE @VAR1 DECIMAL(30,22) = 1.4259276982890801000000;
DECLARE @VAR2 DECIMAL(30,22) = 0.4259276982890801000000;
SELECT @VAR1/@VAR2;';
```

You can fix it by  specifying a different precision and scale of the variables:

```
DECLARE @VAR1 DECIMAL(23,22) = 1.4259276982890801000000;
DECLARE @VAR2 DECIMAL(22,22) = 0.4259276982890801000000;
SELECT @VAR1/@VAR2;
```

Comment: Or `select 1.4259276982890801000000, SQL_Variant_Property( 1.4259276982890801000000, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType, SQL_Variant_Property( 1.4259276982890801000000, 'Precision' ) as Precision, SQL_Variant_Property( 1.4259276982890801000000, 'Scale' ) as Scale;`.

Comment: Great illustration +1.  More of a sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set() myself  :)

Comment: interesting. But again how to fix it. Since I narrowed down my question to 1 simple division. However my entire calculation (in a stored procedure) starts with 5 input values and dividing multiple times e.g. `@Var1 / @Var2 / @Var3 / @Var4 / @Var5` You get the idea. And of course my calculations also contains sum, substract, multiply and power. So I cannot simply define the precision of all 'sub' outcomes

Comment: @hwcverwe, I don't have an easy solution when the declared precision and scale of each expression is different than the actual values because SQL Server will need to accommodate potentially very large/small values for each intermediate and final result. Note that if you declare the variables as `decimal(17,16)`, the result is the more accurate 3.347816317222208507876.